# How does web browser caching work when a new tcp connection is created by the web server?

Tags: c, windows, browser, tcp

During normal browser caching, will a browser re-fetch all file contents if the web server breaks and reopens a tcp connection to the client?

Or will it still cache all contents and only update what has changed, upon the new socket (no difference)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers operate via HTTP protocol. What they can cache and for how long is determined by special [instructions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) of the HTTP protocol (e.g. cache-control header).

Those instructions can be specified by web server. On the other hand browsers can try to cache as much as possible unless it is forbidden by special HTTP instruction or it violates HTTP protocol, or leads to unpredictable behaviour.

Concerning caching and new TCP connections: TCP here is a mere transport for HTTP protocol, so it should have no impact on browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers will cache as much of the content as they can and only re-fetch portions that have changed. Of course, this is necessarily limited by the size of the browser's cache, whether the remote web server properly informs the browser of the age of the components it is trying to fetch, etc.